# Lsmeans: Is this what I did?

Tags: r, paired-comparisons

after doing the linear mixed model with lme4, I have used lsmeans for pairwise comparison with this command:

```
lsmeans(lmer52, pairwise~color, adjust="tukey")
```

I am not sure if it is "multiple pairwise comparisons, using Least Squares Means
 (LSMEANS) and Tukey's adjustment". Anyone have any idea if it is exactly the same thing?

Answer (score 1):

I just saw this. Yes, it is all pair wise comparisons, using a P value adjustment based on the Tukey HSD method.